# How do I correctly update the health state of a node in a networked SIS epidemic?

Tags: python, networkx, simulation

I have to simulate an networked SIS epidemic using discrete time-steps. It's important that each time step of the algorithm can be executed separately, since I want to do something in-between these disease-spreading time steps. However, the results of the program I have written do not match those of, for example, using the `fast_SIS()` function of the [`EoN`](https://epidemicsonnetworks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) Python library.

Here's my code:

```py
for ix in self.net.nodes():
    if self.agent_is_infected(ix): # node is infected
        if rng.random() < gamma:
            self.net.nodes[ix][self.A_HEALTH] = self.H_SUSCEPTIBLE
    else: # node is susceptible
        infected_neighs = [n for n in self.net.neighbors(ix) if self.agent_is_infected(n)]
        prob = 1 - prod([1 - get_esr(ix, n, beta, alpha) for n in infected_neighs])
        
        if rng.random() < prob:
            self.net.nodes[ix][self.A_HEALTH] = self.H_INFECTED
```

With `gamma` = 1 and `beta` = 0.01 (which is what `get_esr()` (i.e. get effective spreading rate) returns, at the moment), the results **should** be:

[image: Networked SIS Epidemic using fast_SIS() from EoN]

And what I am getting is something similar to what `basic_discrete_SIS()` from `EoN` produces:
[image: Networked SIS Epidemic using basic_discrete_SIS() from EoN]

What am I doing wrong, and how could I get the theoretically correct results that `fast_SIS()` produces, while maintaining discrete time steps?

Thank you so much in advance!